# jQuery dropdown using divs instead of li elements

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

## jQuery dropdown using div's instead of li elements

I've been working with a developer to create a dropdown interface on a project that uses the codeigniter framework to dynamically add content to a navigation bar.

Unfortunately the navigation doesn't use the traditional method of a unordered list inside a nav element instead the html looks like this:

you can see the project at http://www.jamesbratton.co.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/

I've been able to get the drop downs to appear, and disappear as intended however hovering is an issue, when I hover over the submenu I'm still loosing the element to a slideUp function.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

### index.html

```
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menu_home center floatleft large white" href="/" title="Home">Home</a>
    <a onmouseover="slideDownDropDown('menu_about-us');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_about-us');" class="cursor-pointer menu_about-us center floatleft large white" title="About Us">About Us</a>
    <a onmouseover="slideDownDropDown('menu_portfolio');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_portfolio');" class="cursor-pointer menu_portfolio center floatleft large white" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a onmouseover="slideDownDropDown('menu_services');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_services');" class="cursor-pointer menu_services center floatleft large white" title="Services">Services</a>
    <a class="menu_contact-us center floatleft large white" href="/contact" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
    <!--menu_about-us, menu_portfolio, menu_services classes are all used in the functions that show/hide other divs, as their id's are reliant on these base classes for show/hide. Jquery needs to add the classes of menu_# to an array. Then on hover query these and if they have a dropdowns_# then show that div.-->                                 
</div>

<div onmouseover="showDropDown('menu_about-us');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_about-us');" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns_menu_about-us" style="display: none;">
    <a class="menu_history white" href="/history" title="History">History</a>
    <a class="menu_clients white" href="/home" title="Clients">Clients</a>
    <a class="menu_certifications white" href="/home" title="Certifications">Certifications</a>
</div>

<div onmouseover="showDropDown('menu_portfolio');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_portfolio');" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns_menu_portfolio" style="display: none;">
    <a onmouseover="showSubDropDown(1);" class="bold cursor-pointer white" title="CategoryName2">CategoryName2</a>
    <a onmouseover="showSubDropDown(2);" class="bold cursor-pointer white" title="New Category">New Category</a>
</div>

<div class="dropdowns"  id="dropdowns_menu_projects" style="display: none;">
    <a class="white subdropdown subdropdowns_1" href="/test-project" title="Test Project">Test Project</a>
    <a class="white subdropdown subdropdowns_2" href="/limestone-mill-tickhill" title="Limestone Hill Mill, Tickhill">Limestone Hill Mill, Tickhill</a>
    <a class="white subdropdown subdropdowns_2" href="/case-study-3" title="Case Study 3">Case Study 3</a>
</div>

<div onmouseover="showDropDown('menu_services');" onmouseout="hideDropDown('menu_services');" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns_menu_services" style="display: none;">
    <a class="menu_contracts white" href="/contracts" title="Contracts">Contracts</a>
    <a class="menu_joinery white" href="/joinery" title="Joinery">Joinery</a>
    <a class="menu_home-building white" href="/home-building" title="Home Building">Home Building</a>
</div>
```

This is just the printout code from the source of the webpage, as the php framework drops it's variables into place.

As you can see the div with the id="menu" is the top level navigation element, all other divs are hidden and represent dropdown divs.

### main.js

```
function slideDownDropDown(id)
  {
var id;
$('#dropdowns_' + id).slideDown("fast");
$('#menu .' + id).addClass("menu-hover");
  }

function slideUpDropDown(id)
  {
var id;
$('#dropdowns_' + id).slideUp();
$('#menu .' + id).removeClass("menu-hover");
  }

function showDropDown(id)
 {

var id;
$('#dropdowns_' + id).show();
$('#menu .' + id).addClass("menu-hover");
 }

function hideDropDown(id)
 {
if($("#dropdowns_" + id).is(':hover'))
{
return 0;
}
else
{
    var id;
    $('#dropdowns_' + id).slideUp("fast");
    $('#menu .' + id).removeClass("menu-hover");
}
 }


function showSubDropDown(id)
 {
var id;
$('#dropdowns_menu_projects').show();
$('.subdropdown').hide();
$('.subdropdowns_' + id).show();
 }

function hideSubDropDown(id)
{
var id;
$('#dropdowns_menu_projects').hide();
$('.subdropdowns_' + id).hide();
 }
```

Comment: If you're passing `id` as a parameter you shouldn't then also declare it inside the functions with `var id;` - get rid of all of them

Comment: When you are using jQuery, Why you are still using inline event binding? like `onmouseover="showDropDown('menu_portfolio');"`

Comment: we're using inline event binding because we're droping Id's of elements in dynamically using php, so in the view file it actually reads onmouseover="showDropDown(<?php echo event->id;)"

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle. http:jsfiddle.net